# .wav sound file stored on server does NOT play when Loaded in web application

Tags: audio, media, wav

this is the scenario i'm trying to achieve: a sound stored on the same server as a web application, plays when a condition is met on the client. It works perfectly when I run it in the IDE and change the webconfig to point to the server where the DB is. However when I deploy it and access it via the browser, the sound does not play. The same sound that played when i used my development machine. Code is:

```
 var configsetings = new System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader();
 string soundPath= configsetings.GetValue("Notification",typeof(System.String)).ToString();
 var sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer { SoundLocation = Server.MapPath(soundPath) };
 sound.Load();
 sound.Play();
```

web config is:

```
<add key="Notification" value="~/beep-4.wav" />
```

The sound file is sitting in the root folder of the ASP.NET web application. So what could be wrong? There is no audio output device on the server neither is there a player like media player nevertheless these factors did NOT stop it from working in my dev machine.

Comment: I did not read your question properly the first time. If there is no audio output device on the player, how do you expect the file to be played? I hope you do not expect to hear it on the client...

Comment: I actually do because it worked as I explained when I ran the VS2010 project on my machine against the same server and with the same web config file no changes. The server is supposed to just store the the sound file which gets played on the client. So I am wondering why it doesn't play.

Comment: The code you wrote runs **on the server**, not on the client, hence, you are tring to play your audio file on the server, without having a sound card in it. This will never work. Good luck.

Comment: so that would mean I have to install a sound card on the server and on the client right? or else how the user on the client side hear the sound? Please explain the dynamics of this to me. Thanks again @yms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code you posted I will assume you wrote it in C#.

So, this code will run on the server-side, and the client-side (the web browser) will never know about it or about your audio file. Please read about asp.net code-behind and how it works. If you want to play an audio file in the browser (client-side), you need to use either [javascript](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/sound/play.htm), or flash, or the [< audio >  tag from html5](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp).

By installing a sound card on a server you will only achieve (in a best case scenario) to get the file played on that server.

Comment: Thanks @yms just checked and found that the mime type .wav was already in the Features List. Any other thing I could check out?

Comment: Wow, I see! The scenario is one in which the sound plays on if a certain condition is met and this condition is checked on the server side since it reads data from the DB to check. That's why I put it on the server side. I guess I will have to find an implementation that can trigger of an embedded sound on the client's browser that doesn't play until it is triggered! Thanks for the assistance though I would not mind more [Oliver Twist like me:)]

Comment: You can always have an aspx webpage or a webservice to verify the condition you need to check on the server, and access this webpage or webservice with javascript (using ajax maybe?) or Flash.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks yms, the  tag worked. I put a routine that writes the tag's HTML to a div at run time and put it in a timer.

```
sounddiv.InnerHtml = "<audio preload=\"auto\" autoplay=\"autoplay\">" +
            "<source src=\"" + soundPath + "\" type=\"audio/wav\" />" +
            " Your browser does not support the audio tag. </audio>";
```

This code is called in the code behind in a timer in response to the condition.
So the sound repeats every 30 seconds. Problem solved. Thanks guys for the leads.